# FFI: returning three Int#'s on the stack

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

Is there any way to return three `Int#` on the stack from a foreign function call? Here is the C code (or C code that generates an object file equivalent to the one I'm actually interested in):

```
struct Tuple {
  int bezout1, bezout2, gcd;
}

struct Tuple extendedGcd(int a, int b) {
  /* elided */
}
```

This won't compile since `(# Int#, Int#, Int# #)` isn't supported by `ccall`:

```
foreign import ccall "extendedGcd"
  extendedGcd :: Int# -> Int# -> (# Int#, Int#, Int# #)
```

All my uses of the following (which compiles, albeit with `MagicHash`, `GHCForeignImportPrim`, `ForeignFunctionInterface`, `UnboxedTuples`, and `MagicHash`) seg-fault:

```
foreign import prim "extendedGcd"
  extendedGcd :: Int# -> Int# -> (# Int#, Int#, Int# #)
```

I can find some evidence that there was some effort to get around this sort of problem:

- [thread on the mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2014-March/004301.html)
- [a proposed (but abandoned) `CStructures` GHC extension](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CStructures) (by the same person)

I imagine this is a common issue, yet I can't find any working examples. Is this at all possible? If it isn't does anyone care about this anymore (is there a Trac ticket somewhere?)

Comment: What is the type of the C function you're importing? I think its type in C determines entirely what type you can assign to it in Haskell. `ccall` is intended to model the C calling convention; since there is no concept of multiple return in C itself, it isn't present in `ccall` either. I think the proposals for automatic struct marshalling were scraped in favour of using `c2hs` or the like to automatically generate the code to marshal structs.

Comment: @user2407038 Sure it has a C type (I've included some code), but the `Storable` instances `c2hs` generates all assume I'm passing a pointer. Here, I'd like to pass an unboxed product (just three raw ints on the stack). My understanding is that the only way to do that in Haskell is via unboxed tuples.

Comment: Indeed, there's no easy way to return a struct from a C function without allocating temporary memory somewhere. If this is too great a performance penalty (or some other obstacle to doing so), the only option is to use `prim` and return an unboxed tuple as you've done. But if your function is a regular C function, it won't conform to the GHC call conventions which `prim` functions are required to use. You'd have to write a C-- wrapper around your function.

Comment: @user2407038 I would love to see an example of that!

Comment: I've managed to find one such [example](https://bitbucket.org/carter/who-ya-gonna-call-talk-may-2013-ny-haskell/src/68c62ffd82e48c533491792275cd7ac2b1d678a1/FunShim/c4hs.c) (and the associated [talk](https://vimeo.com/69025829)). Although in practice if you want this to be portable you would need much more code.

Comment: [Another example](http://breaks.for.alienz.org/blog/2012/02/09/parsing-market-data-feeds-with-ragel/)

Comment: @user2407038 Yeah - I've read the second one a couple of times. There is an annoying caveat: "Many messages don’t fit within the 5 free registers (R2-R6) that are available here and need to be partially loaded onto the stack. In this example I’m just discarding the ‘printable’ flag to make everything fit in registers. Managing the stack is more involved"

Comment: I guess you'd have to dive into the GHC internals at this point, which is mainly undocumented... Probably the code which generates FFI wrappers for `ccall` imports would be a good place to start (if you're prepared for such a non-trivial undertaking, that is!)

Answer (score 1):

If you can implement your procedure in assembly directly, rather than C, it's pretty easy to do this. See: http://brandon.si/code/almost-inline-asm-in-haskell-with-foreign-import-prim/ . Maybe for a GCD algorithm this will be okay for you.

There is a complete cabal project I put together [here](https://github.com/jberryman/almost-inline-asm-haskell-example).

Comment: Oh this isn't actually for GCD. This is for generating Haskell interop with Rust tuples. :) This is nonetheless useful! Thank you.